# Programmatically set featured images

Tags: images

Is there a way to set featured images in bulk? I have created a bunch of posts (200+) and would like to set featured images to all of them in bulk - without using the admin panel and setting the featured image for each post one by one?

Comment: Is there a way to search this site? There is! Try this one: [search: featured images programmatically](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=featured%20images%20Programmatically).

Comment: Thank you! Does the thread you provided imply that the image has to be attached to the post, or can it be any image from within the media library?

Comment: I actually just provided the link to the search, but like Chris_O says in his answer: »You can run a script that will programmatically set the featured image for each post. You can use the first attached image for this.« So his code does just that. Of course you can do it differently, but then you have to implement some (other) logic on how to select the according image. Good luck!